# Google apps script – Finding and copying new data (googlesheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day everyone.

There is table 1 (Data Source), where new operations are loaded every day (1 operation = 1 row). The number of transactions per day is arbitrary. In the last column (Operation Type), you must manually specify the type of operation.

There is table 2 (Direct Sales), which should be automatically loaded with all new transactions from the data source table that have the required transaction type (in the example, this is the "Direct Sales" type).

According to the guides, I wrote a script that copies data from table 1 to table 2, but the problem is that on each run it copies ALL the relevant data, creating duplicates in table 2 from the second run.

I understand that the script needs to be improved so that when adding new data to table 1:

1. found in table 1 the last row from table 2 (duplicates are not allowed)
2. ran through all the rows below it in table 1 (search for new suitable operations)
3. took all rows with the required type of operation to table 2 (copying new operations)

But there are not enough competencies for this kind of modernization (unfortunately, far from programming), I got stuck at the stage of comparing two data arrays. I tried to look for similar cases, but everywhere it is proposed to clear the page after removing the necessary data (which is unacceptable in my case, the data in table 1 should remain), respectively, and line enumeration is not considered there.

I would be grateful if someone can help refine the script or direct me in which direction to look / show similar examples so that there is a place to peep.

(in the example, I placed both tables in the same file on different sheets, and reduced the number of columns for visual ease. But the important point is that you will need to compare the entire row in order to load only unique operations)

Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ry6wEiagZzNGA4rN2TlaKML3AkoFvgLz1Om8o854F_g/edit#gid=1217659551

The code I managed to write:

```
function copyrows(){

const ss_sourse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data Sourse");
const ss_target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Direct Sales");
const ss_sourse_lr = ss_sourse.getLastRow();
const ss_target_lr = ss_target.getLastRow();

let sortRange = ss_sourse.getSheetValues(3,1,ss_sourse_lr, 6);
let b2b_direct = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++){
  let name = ss_sourse.getRange(i,6).getValue();

  if (name == "Direct Sales"){
    let rowValues = ss_sourse.getRange(i, 1, 1, 6).getValues();
    ss_target.getRange(ss_target_lr+b2b_direct, 1, 1, 6).setValues(rowValues);
    b2b_direct++;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `1. found in table 1 the last row from table 2 (duplicates are not allowed) 2. ran through all the rows below it in table 1 (search for new suitable operations) 3. took all rows with the required type of operation to table 2 (copying new operations)`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hi and welcome. "problem is that on each run it copies ALL the relevant data, creating duplicates in table 2 from the second run." Easily fixed: clear existing data from "Direct Sales" and run the script on all data on "Data Sourse". In fact, I think this is necessary anyway because transactions do not appear to have a unique identifier (such as an invoice/transaction number); so there is no way to recognise whether a transaction on "Data Sales" is a "real" duplicate or just an apparent duplicate.

Comment: "But the important point is that you will need to compare the entire row in order to load only unique operations". What if a customer had two identical transaction on the same day?

Comment: "I understand that the script needs to be improved so that when adding new data to table 1". OK, it sounds like you want to "automatically" trigger the script when new data is entered in Table 1. BUT... there are 6 columns of data (and sometimes only 5 columns) in each row so how would you suggest that the script should identify that the data entry for a new line has been completed?

Comment: "but everywhere it is proposed to clear the page after removing the necessary data (which is unacceptable in my case, the data in table 1 should remain)" You don't clear Table 1 (Data Sourse), you clear Table2 (Direct Sales) then recreate Table2 by re-running the script on all of the data on Table 1. The trigger to re-run is manual, or maybe timed.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't a QUERY fit your needs?? Write in a new tab:

```
=QUERY('Data Source'!A2:F,"Where F = 'Direct Sales'")
```

With that formula you'd have a constant track of your MasterSheet without any coding